# Console App C# simples no Visual Studio 2017, fecha sem mostrar o resultado

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Estou a tentar executar um simples programa que escreva "Hello world" no VS2017:

```
namespace OlaMundo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int num;

            System.Console.WriteLine("Número :");

         num = System.Console.Read();

            System.Console.WriteLine(num);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Tecle enter para fechar...");

        System.Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
}
```

porém ao executá-lo me deparo com o seguinte problema:

```
"OlaMundo.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Carregado "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll". Não é possível localizar ou abrir o arquivo PDB.
"OlaMundo.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Carregado "C:\Users\tiago\source\repos\C#\01_Hello_world\OlaMundo\OlaMundo\bin\Debug\OlaMundo.exe". Símbolos carregados.
O programa "[1688] OlaMundo.exe" foi fechado com o código 0 (0x0).
```

Já desabilitei a opção "*Just my code*" e também já apaguei a pasta "*bin*" do projeto e recompilei novamente. Porém, não obtive nenhum êxito.

Comment: @TiagoSantos, Conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente não há nada de errado, o console fecha porque a aplicação terminou seu fluxo... se quer manter a janela aberta e ficar lendo o "Hello, Wolrd", adicione um ponto de espera, como a entrada de algum valor.

Já o seu segundo problema é porque você não está convertendo o tipo e usando o método errado. Todas entradas via console são do tipo String, no seu código você precisa validar e converter para o tipo esperado.

```
namespace OlaMundo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int num;
            Console.WriteLine("Número :");
            num = Convert.ToInt32(System.Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine(num);

            //Adicione esse trecho ao final da sua Main
            #if DEBUG
            Console.WriteLine("Tecle enter para fechar...");
            Console.ReadLine();
            #endif
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Resolveu", porém, quando declaro  variável no mesmo programa, inserido os dados através do console, ele fecha antes de mostrar o resultado do que eu inseri na tela. Além de voltar o mesmo aviso na saída.

Comment: É a mesma coisa, sempre deixa um `Console.Read()` no final para você poder manter o console aberto enquanto debuga. E não é "resolveu", essa é a solução.

Comment: Quando declaro  variável tipo *int* no mesmo programa, inserindo os dados através do console, ele fecha antes de mostrar o resultado do que eu inseri na tela. Além de voltar o mesmo aviso na saída.

Comment: Veja a edição da minha resposta. E adicione o resto do seu código a pergunta, o problema provavelmente é mesmo, mas tá virando outra pergunta :P.

Comment: Bom, foi justamente a solução da resposta editada que apliquei, o que mandou o mesmo retorno de saída, fechando o console quando uso variáveis do tipo int, o que não acontece com strings.